# how to hide <select> element by onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an  element which is set to display:none in css.
When the parent element gets clicked then the select appears through

```
document.getElementById('selectId').style.display = 'block';
```

Now I want that after some option is selected, the selector disappears.

When calling `style.display = 'none'` from onchange then it blinks for a fraction of a second and is again visible. I even checked with `console.log(obj.style.display)` and indeed the display changes quick.

How can I achieve this behavior: `display = 'none'` by `onchange` ?

Pure JavsScript or JQuery does not matter

**Edit:** It looks like the `onchange` event on the `<select>` triggers the `onclick` for the parent which resets the display to 'block'.

**Code and Solution**: on the suggestion from @AndyG I modified the function which gets called by the onchange event like this:

```
function selChanged(obj) {
    $(obj).click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    obj.style.display = 'block';
}
```

And now it wont trigger the parent 'onclick' anymore.
Here the html code:

```
<td onclick="showSelect(selId)">
    <select id="selId" onchange="selChanged(this)">
       <option>
         ....
       </option>
</td>
```

Comment: `.hide()` and `.show()` will help u ;)

Comment: What is the rest of your code? Sounds like something is turning it back on

Comment: More code would help. I guess that selecting an item allows the click event to bubble to the parent element, causing its click event again. `event.stopPropagation()` would prevent this, or perhaps using `focus` rather than click. (Although the parent probably won't have a focus event (unless it has a tabindex).)

Comment: @AndyG Yes it seems so - I just edited the question. And thanks for the suggestion - I'll try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the selection is changed by clicking an option, this click event will bubble up to the parent element, causing the select to reappear.

`event.stopPropagation();` in the change event will prevent this bubbling to the parent.

Comment: The principle can be tested by using the keyboard to select an option (tabbing, Alt-Down, Down, Enter), which will not involve a click.

Answer (score 0):

Whit jQuery..

`$('#selectId').hide()` to hide it

`$('#selectId').show()` to show it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```